# How to test the convergence of $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{3^n(n-1)(-1)^n}{n^3}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

So $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{3^n(n-1)(-1)^n}{n^3}=\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{(-3)^n(n-1)}{n^3}$. Then I fail to continue. Is there a way to simplify it?

Comment: aren't you forgetting the variable $x$?

Comment: It is Alternating series...Use Libnitz test..

Answer (score 2):

One has, as $n \to \infty$,
$$
\left|\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}\right|=\left|\frac{3^{n+1}n(-1)^{n+1}}{(n+1)^3}\times\frac{n^3}{3^n(n-1)(-1)^n}{}\right| \to 3>1
$$ thus the series is **divergent**.

Answer (score 1):

The series diverge. It is comparable to sigma 3^n/n^2 and the terms of this approaches infinity as n goes to infinity.